# If I'm using a connection pool to run two separate queries, should I release my connection and connect again before the second query?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm using the [PG npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) to run queries with node.js and PostgreSQL. I'm assuming that it's best practice for multiple queries to use the same connection without releasing it and obtaining it again before the second query.  Right?

I am confused about the example code shown below.  After obtaining a connection from the pool, the query is run inside a callback.  What if I want to run a second query with the same connection?  Another callback?  How could this code be rewritten with a Promise library to avoid callback hell?

```
var pg = require('pg');
var conString = "postgres://username:password@localhost/database";

//this initializes a connection pool 
//it will keep idle connections open for a (configurable) 30 seconds 
//and set a limit of 10 (also configurable) 
pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done) {
  if(err) {
    return console.error('error fetching client from pool', err);
  }
  client.query('SELECT $1::int AS number', ['1'], function(err, result) {
    //call `done()` to release the client back to the pool 
    done();

    if(err) {
      return console.error('error running query', err);
    }
    console.log(result.rows[0].number);
    //output: 1 
  });
});
```

Comment: To avoid all that pain, you can use [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), which manages the connection automatically.

Comment: Honestly, I would follow @vitaly-t advise. No point in reinventing the wheel. Although he might be a bit biased, it being he module and all haha. Jk. It is a well respected library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well a naive approach is this:

```js
function runQuery(sql) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const connectionString = `postgres://${db_config.USERNAME}:${db_config.PASSWORD}@${db_config.HOST}/${db_config.DATABASE}`;

    const client = new pg.Client(connectionString);

    client.connect(connectErr => {
      if (connectErr) {
        throw new Error(connectErr);
      }

      client.query(sql, (queryErr, result) => {
        if (queryErr) {
          return reject(new Error(queryErr));
        }

        client.end();

        return resolve(result);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Another, probably better option is to take advantage of the fact that the module queues queries for you

`database.js`

```js
const connectionString = `postgres://${db_config.USERNAME}:${db_config.PASSWORD}@${db_config.HOST}/${db_config.DATABASE}`;

const client = new pg.Client(connectionString);

client.connect(connectErr => {
  if (connectErr) {
    throw new Error(connectErr);
  }
});

module.exports.query = function runQuery(sql) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    
      var query = client.query(sql);
    
      query.on('row', function(row, result) {
        result.addRow(row);
      });
    
      query.on('end', function(result) {
        resolve(result);
      });
      
      query.on('error', function(err) {
        reject(new Error(err));
      });
      
    });
  };
```

EDIT: I made a quick edit that used the result object passed as the 2nd parameter to the `row` event instead of creating my own array